# Change Skus in message using Magmi

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, magmi, sku

Is there a way to change SKU's en masse using Magmi?

My goal is to change from:

`2040-15K9-01-Pal`

to:

`2040-15K9`

What would the be the best way to do something like this?

Note: A regular expression solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If youre just adding the same suffix to all products, do this:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku` = concat(`sku`, "-SUFFIX")
```

edit: If you just want to strip the suffix from all product skus, do this:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku` = replace(`sku`, "-SUFFIX", "")
```

Then reindex for flat catalogs. (tested/confirmed working)

Comment: I think the OP is trying to *remove* the second half of the suffix.

Comment: @philwinkle i am terrible at following directions! updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer does not use Magmi.**

I try to avoid direct database queries. This PHP script will set the SKU based on the first two sections separated by the `-` characters:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product){
    $baseSku = $product->getSku();
    $sku = explode('-',$baseSku);
    $product->setSku($sku[0] . '-' . $sku[1]);

    $product->save();
}
```

**A word of warning:**

I have seen, on 1.7CE/1.12EE and lower, all sorts of deadlock issues crop up even on local dev boxes with no production traffic. In that case I highly recommend you implement a deadlock workaround such as my Github module https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_DeadlockRetry

Or implement your own `saferSave` or retry method.

Best of luck.

Comment: To get better through the update process, you may set the indexing mode to manual update. Speeds up the process, decreases deadlocks (at least for me).

Comment: Doesn't prevent deadlocks in all versions regardless of indexing mode.

Comment: Right, it doesn't prevent deadlocks (and deadlocks itself aren't something horrible to start with) but it may help to reduce the number of deadlocks as the number of write/delete operations during the process are reduced. My comment wasn't meant to be a replacement for your extension.

Comment: No worries at all, I didn't take it as such. Useful feedback from you all around. Thanks!